# Grouping list of anagrams from a list of words without using in-built iterable functions of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, anagram

input: list of strings

```
I = ["top","doom","pot","mood","cigar"]
```

output: list of sets (in any order) where each set contains a group of anagrams from input

```
O = [{"mood", "doom"}, {"cigar"}, {"top", "pot"}]
```

my solution in Python (however, it uses `sorted` which is an in-built python function). What other way I can create a unique `key` for all anagrams before storing them in a `dict` or anyother substitute for `sorted`?

```py
def groupAnagrams(S):
    res = dict()
    for elem in S:
        elem = elem.lower()
        sorted_elem = ''.join(sorted(elem))
        if res.get(sorted_elem) is None:
            res[sorted_elem] = set([elem])
        else:
            res[sorted_elem].add(elem)
    return list(res.values())
```

Comment: counter from collections module is a substitute for sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `frozenset` and `dict.setdefault`:

```
def groupAnagrams(S):
    res = defaultdict(list)

    for k, elem in zip(map(frozenset, S), S):
        res.setdefault(k, set()).add(elem)

    return list(res.values())
```